# how to pass GCC class to MSVC dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

I want to pass a class between a GCC compiled gui app and MSVC dll ?

I want my GUI app to communicate with a plugin DLL,

example:

(Edit i think i wasnt clear. i know this wont work. this is PSEUDOcode. what i asked for is how to make it work and that isint really related to what classes i have :D)

```
class eventbase{ }//virutal copy constructor [edit:cloner .o0]
class eventtype1{} // copy constructor [edit:cloner .o0]
class eventtype2{} // copy constructor [edit:cloner .o0]
```

and pass these events from/to gui/dll ...

i am afraid (well certian actually) this wont work so i ask for a workaround. how do you construct events to pass to your plugins ? how do you manage them ?

Comment: i think it can be done by exposing CreateEventType1(params) in dll. but thats GUI->DLL . still no idea how to do it other way round o0

Comment: ¤ First, there is no such thing as a "virtual copy constructor", and the code you show is not C++ or meaningful at all. That said, to use classes between g++ and Visual C++ you need a a binary level standard, a so called "ABI", and in Windows COM is that ABI. So you're effectively talking about a COM class. Since you want events, check out the COM events documentation. A simpler alternative is to use **the same compiler** for everything. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor and no i will never ever in my life use COM. i cant use the same compiler id rather use tcpip sockets to pushpull events than rewrite half my code :D

Comment: actually the term "virtual constructor" is also in the C++ FAQ. I think it was Coplien who coined it. But using that term nowadays, brands one as incompetent. After all, there is the much more well known term "cloning" (and it your code does not look like cloning, just to point out that). Regarding refusal to use the only technology fulfilling your requirements, well that puts you in a bind, doesn't it? Perhaps the solution then is to do something else entirely. :-)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I figured adding the [gcc] and [visual-c++] tags would be appropriate for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in linkage and C++ mangling.  GCC and MSVC don't result in same-named symbols within the DLL.  The only way around it that I know of is to use C linkage of functions and structures to set up the interface between the application and the plugin DLL. Something like:

```
extern "C"
{
   struct pluginClass
   {
      int pluginVersion;
      void (*plugin_func)();
   };

   pluginClass * myPluginStartup();
   void myPluginShutdown( pluginClass * returnToHeap );
}
```

Unfortunately, this means that you won't be able to pass STL collections or other more complex classes around.  I hope you find a better answer than this, though. I'll keep my eyes open for it.

Comment: this is generaly what i wanted so i accept it as the answer and move on :) i also add that you need a "free api result" function in the dll. you cant just `delete apires;` it because memory management differs in compilers

Comment: Ah, thank you... the shutdown was supposed to take the pointer back, but I guess I went on autopilot. I'll edit to include it properly.